# Get printer names available in system Ext Js 4.1

Tags: javascript

I want to retrieve the available printers in a client-side JavaScript application.

Is there any method to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean local printer names on the client's system?
There is no solution for that in JavaScript.

You could rely on OS/Browser specific ways (ActiveX for instance) or a Java applet maybe.

(In that light, I don't think this is an Ext JS 4.1 specific-question.)

What are you trying to accomplish if I may ask?

Comment: Hi..thanks for your suggestions.I am  designing a form in sencha extjs,in that I want to set printer name,track,number of copies etc and these values are send to a webservice as parameters ,in which print operation is done.

Comment: That clarifies a lot.

What you want to do is ask the same webservice to give you the list of printers it has access too (and the other information you need).

The printers you want to show are not the local printers on the end-user's computer (if JavaScript could do that, that would be the result), but you are offering the list of printers the webservice uses to the end-user.
You should basically ask this question with the language tag of the webservice, not JavaScript.